# h2o AutoML algo_parameters usage

Tags: python, h2o

I am trying to run `H2OAutoML` in a specific way. I am only running XGBOOST, and I only want stratified folds, along with only using `booster = 'gbtree'` (i.e. I don't want `booster = 'dart'` in the hyper-parameter search)

I have tried:

```
    aml = H2OAutoML(
        nfolds=5, 
        include_algos=['XGBoost'], 
        sort_metric='auc', 
        seed=1, 
        max_runtime_secs=10,
        algo_parameters=dict(booster = 'gbtree')
    )
```

But get the error:

```
  Error: Illegal value for field: algo_parameters: booster
  Request: POST /99/AutoMLBuilder
    json: {'build_control': {'stopping_criteria': {'max_runtime_secs': 10, 
    'stopping_metric': 'AUTO', 'stopping_rounds': 3, 'seed': 1}, 'nfolds': 5, 
    'balance_classes': False, 'max_after_balance_size': 5.0, 
   'keep_cross_validation_models': False, 'keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment': 
   False, 'keep_cross_validation_predictions': False}, 'build_models': 
   {'include_algos': ['XGBoost'], 'exploitation_ratio': 0, 'algo_parameters': 
   [{'scope': 'any', 'name': 'booster', 'value': 'gbtree'}]}, 'input_spec': 
   {'sort_metric': 'auc', 'training_frame': 'py_1_sid_928f', 'response_column': 
   'successful', 'weights_column': 'weight', 'ignored_columns': ['C1']}}
```

Comment: From the [list of parameters](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html#optional-miscellaneous-parameters), the 'algo_parameters' is not available. So, although you can filter which algorithms you want to run, I think you cannot filter the hyperparameters of that algorithm.

Comment: Since you only want to run XGBoost, you can build yourself a [grid search](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/grid-search.html) with that algorithm, specifying the hyperparameters you want to try. You can even copy the hyperparameters that are used by the AutoML for [XGBoost](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html#xgboost-hyperparameters)

Answer (score 0):

This is an [undocumented parameter](https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7551) (used internally for testing), so although I will post how to do it here, you should not count on this parameter as something that will always be available.  Use at your own risk!

The reason that you're getting this error is that this is only available when you start H2O with special Java flags.  In Python, you have to start H2O like this:

```
# Start H2O with custom algo_parameters option enabled
h2o.init(jvm_custom_args=["-Dsys.ai.h2o.automl.algo_parameters.all.enabled=true"])
```

And then this will work:

```
aml = H2OAutoML(
    nfolds=5, 
    include_algos=['XGBoost'], 
    sort_metric='auc', 
    seed=1, 
    max_runtime_secs=10,
    algo_parameters=dict(XGBoost__booster = 'gbtree')
)
```

*Note: you should pre-pend the algorithm name to the parameter name with two underscores, so it knows which algo to use it in, even if you only include XGBoost, it's good to be verbose.*